# RISC-V specification version change after ratification

Tags: riscv

It is unclear to me why there is a version change from 1.11 to 1.12 in the RISC-V Machine and Supervisor ISA specifications even though 1.11 is listed as **ratified** ([link to the spec](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Priv-v1.12/riscv-privileged-20211203.pdf)).

I thought that once an extension is ratified, changes are no longer possible according to
the [specification states](https://wiki.riscv.org/display/HOME/Specification+States) and the [specification lifecycle](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1nQ5uFb39KA6gvUi5SReWfIQSiRN7hp6z7ZPfctE4mKk/edit#slide=id.p1).

I assume that either my understanding of what "ratified" means or the way versioning works is flawed so I would appreciate it if somebody could clarify it or point me to the relevant resources where this is explained.

Comment: Do you have a source claiming the status of 1.11 is ratified?

Comment: Yes, look at the [spec](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Priv-v1.12/riscv-privileged-20211203.pdf). In the preface for version 1.11, the Machine and Supervisor ISAs are listed as ratified.

Comment: Ok, I see that, but that's the version 1.12.  I can't find 1.11 alone, do you have it?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Ratified-IMFDQC-and-Priv-v1.11/riscv-privileged-20190608.pdf